# Lagrange interpolation and Weierstrass theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Let $f$ be an integrable function in $[a,b]$. Define, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$I_{n}(f) := \sum_{j=0}^{n} w_{j,n}f(x_{j,n})$$ to numerically approximate $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$. (In the context of Weierstrass theorem) prove that if:

$I_{n}(f) \rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ for all function in some dense family of $C[a,b]$ and $\sup_{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n} w_{j,n}< \infty $.
Then $I_{n}(f)  \rightarrow \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$  for all $f \in C[a,b]$.

I think I have to use Lagrange interpolation to relate some concepts for the proof but I don't know how to use Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You usually approximate functions with Weirstrass, not integrals. Since this is a definite integral, you are obtaining a scalar/Real value. Can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hint is rather than a full solution. This is a problem where you must assert control over the term $I(f) - I_n(f)$ where $I(f) = \int_a^b f(x) dx$. To that end, you *must* introduce terms over which you have control. By assumption, there is a sequence of functions $\{f_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ such that $f_m \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $C([a,b])$ and such that $I_n(f_m) \rightarrow I(f_m)$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and each fixed value of $m$. This suggest to me that we should write
$$ I(f) - I_n(f) = \big[ I(f) - I(f_m) \big] + \big[I(f_m) - I_n(f_m) \big]+ \big[I_n(f_m) - I_n(f)\big].$$
Now try to assert control over each of the three terms in the square brackets. You will need to use your assumption about the weights $W_{j,n}$. Check to see if you are allowed to assume that the $w_{j,n}$ are non-negative.

Comment: In fact, either one would need some nonnegativity hypothesis on $w_{j, n}$ or impose that $\sup_n \sum_{j = 0}^n |w_{j, n}| < \infty$. Indeed, if $I_n(f) \to I(f)$ for all $f \in C[a, b]$, then each $I_n$ must be a bounded operator (uniform boundedness principle). In turn, $\|I_n\| = \sum_{j = 0}^n |w_{j, n}|$ is bounded (uniformly in $n$).